# bring the Ylabels close to each other

Tags: android, achartengine

I've done a chart i my Android app with Achartengine. In my graph there are three ylabels  called for example: "A", "B", "C". When i show my graph, these ylabels go one in the center of the yaxis, one on the top and one on the bottom. I would have these ylabels more close and not in the bottom or top of the graph.

For example i used this to set the ylabels on the right side of my yaxis:

```
mrenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT,0);
```

But how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can try customizing the graph like this by setting.

mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 0);

mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);